# Swarm/crowd movement with box2d?

Tags: c++, 2d, physics

Apart from using b2Body::setTransform(), are there other ways to move a body around while keeping its dynamics ?

I want to move several bodies at the same time into one direction, pretty much like the movement of a crowd like the units in starcraft 2.

Does box2d already provide such features, if yes what is this called ? If not what precautions should I take while using setTransform ?

Comment: Have you looked at the concept of flocking/boids?

Comment: do they collide with each other ?

Comment: Look at Bytes answer. One of the rules keeps them seperated.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the same as implementing a boids algorithm, and using Box2D to apply the forces required:

- Separation: Steer to avoid crowding local flockmates
- Alignment: Steer towards the average heading of local flockmates
- Cohesion: Steer to move toward the average position of local flockmates

You can see an example in action [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) and get some [details on its implementation here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/).

Applying the forces would be with Box2D functions to apply forces or impulses. You can read up of those [here](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/forces).

Comment: Can I still set an arriving behaviour with boids ?

Comment: Absolutely. It actually allows you to ensure your entities aren't all crowding the arrival point. You can either use a follow the leader method and just have one entity arrive as normal, or use the above forces in addition to an arrival algorithm to make the entire flock exhibit the arrival behavior. As long as you maintain the 3 forces mentioned above, along with the steering force, you'll be set.

Comment: steering involves orientation, I want to do this without orientation.

Comment: @jokoon It doesn't have to. Essentially you'll just have instantaneous rotation. This is easier to implement than steering with orientation.

Comment: How do I steer with box2d ?

Comment: Apply a force in the direction you want the object to go.

Comment: if it already has velocity it's not going to work, I have to cancel out the existing velocity

Comment: I think you're not understanding some things. Talk about it in chat.

Comment: I managed to implement the arrival behavior thanks to the pseudocode of the '99 GDC paper. problem now, they bump into each other and shake. The problem with cohesion and separation is that it requires a query test...

Comment: I guess all I need is to implement separation now...